What exactly does it mean for the moduli space of stable sheaves to have a universal family étale locally?
It is known that in general, the moduli space $M$ of (Gieseker) stable sheaves do not have a universal family. Therefore, a map $f \colon S \to M$ does not necessarily induce a family of sheaves.
On the other hand, there are references (the book by Huybrechts and Lehn 2nd edition on p.139 or Simpson's paper Theorem 1.21) that state that a universal family exists étale locally.
I was wondering what this meant precisely.
Does it mean that for any scheme $S$ and any map $f \colon S \to M$:

There exists an étale surjective map $\alpha \colon U \to M$ and our "étale-local universal family" $\mathcal{E}$ on $U \times X.$
There exists an étale surjective map $\beta \colon T \to S$ and a map $g \colon T \to U$ such that the map $f\beta \colon T \to S \to M$ corresponds to the family $g^*\mathcal{E},$ i.e., the morphism induced by $g^*\mathcal{E}$ is isomorphic to $f\beta?$


I think it means that the moduli stack $\mathcal{M}$ (the "functor" associating to every $S$ the groupoid of suitable stable sheaves on $S\times X$) admits an etale surjection from a scheme $U$. That is, a natural transformation ${\rm Hom}(-, U)\to \mathcal{M}$ (corresponding by Yoneda to a suitable family of stable sheaves parametrized by $U$) such that every map $X\to \mathcal{M}$ etale locally on $X$ lifts to $U$. This means that every family parametrized by $X$ is etale locally on $X$ the pullback of the family on $U$ via some map. The map to the coarse moduli space $M$ need not be etale.

The local maps $X\to U$ need not be unique (otherwise they would glue to a global map $X\to U$, and then $U\to\mathcal{M}$ would be an isomorphism).

@PiotrAchinger I see, thank you!
